# How to use orderByChild.equalTo in firebase realtime database V9 using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I am new and learning ReactJS. I am writing a code for matching the model text from my code to firebase Realtime database model text.I have stored my model text in state and defined it like this `var modelTxt = this.state.models`. and written my firebase database query like this. and import it like this `import { getDatabase, ref, get, orderByChild } from "firebase/database";` The problem is I am not able to get the data from firebase. Can anyone please check my code and help me with this.

My database structure is like this :

```js
{
070921210001{
"Model": "modelName"
}
}
```

My code

```js
var modelTxt = this.state.models
console.log(modelTxt)

 const dbRef = ref(getDatabase(`/`));
  dbRef.orderByChild(`Model`).equalTo(modelTxt).once("value", function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
  
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

I think I was calling the data in wrong way.Can anyone please help.

Comment: You can see my full code hearer https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-goodall-c003j?file=/src/App.js